# How to catch the bad zip file error in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to extract the stock data for the past month and ran into this error when my code tries to extract stock data on days where there was no trading.

The code stops execution on `datetime.date(2020, 7, 26)` which was a Sunday and so there was no stock trade.

My code :

```py
import datetime
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd

from nsepy.history import get_price_list
today = date.today()

yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
bhav_copy = get_price_list(dt=yesterday)
for i in range(1,30):
    date_ = yesterday - datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    try:
        prices = get_price_list(dt=date_)
    except BadZipFile as e:
        continue
    bhav_copy = bhav_copy.append(prices)
```

Error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-37d75cc40921> in <module>
     13     try:
---> 14         prices = get_price_list(dt=date_)
     15     except BadZipFile as e:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nsepy/history.py in get_price_list(dt, series)
    323     res = price_list_url(yyyy, MMM, dt.strftime("%d%b%Y").upper())
--> 324     txt = unzip_str(res.content)
    325     fp = six.StringIO(txt)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nsepy/commons.py in unzip_str(zipped_str, file_name)
    121 
--> 122     zf = zipfile.ZipFile(file=fp)
    123     if not file_name:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64, compresslevel)
   1257             if mode == 'r':
-> 1258                 self._RealGetContents()
   1259             elif mode in ('w', 'x'):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1324         if not endrec:
-> 1325             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1326         if self.debug > 1:

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-37d75cc40921> in <module>
     13     try:
     14         prices = get_price_list(dt=date_)
---> 15     except BadZipFile as e:
     16         continue
     17     bhav_copy = bhav_copy.append(prices)

NameError: name 'BadZipFile' is not defined
```

I would try to use a try and catch block. I imported the `BadZipFile` module, but run into errors when i try to catch the exception.

Below is the piece of code after the for loop, I guess I don't know how to use try and catch here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include the reason for downvoting my question, I would update or change my question aptly.

Comment: Your code, now it includes `from zipfile import BadZipFile`, will not generate the error `NameError: name 'BadZipFile' is not defined`. Since you've edited some parts of your question and left others as they were, it does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the error you're trying to catch:

```py
from zipfile import BadZipFile
```

Comment: I too used the library, but am not able to catch the exception @SamMorgan. I have updated my question as well.

Comment: Just tested your code with my suggestion and it executes exactly as expected. Add that line to the top of your code and give it a try.